# CSS styling placeholder text

Tags: html, css

I am trying to style placeholder text, but I can't seem to select it. If my input is this:

```
<input id="search" class="search-query" placeholder="Placeholder text here" name="" value"">
```

How can I select the placeholder text in css for styling?

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610497/change-an-inputs-html5-placeholder-color-with-css

Answer (score 15):

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color: red;
}

:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
   color: red;  
}

::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
   color: red;  
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {  
   color: red;  
}

/* All modern browsers except IE and EDGE */
::placeholder { color: red }
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DLGFK/

Comment: Thanks, sorry I am starting using LESS, and that is where I messed up. The above selectors work as intended

Comment: @AlienWebGuy All modern browsers besides IE/EDGE now support the non flagged pseudo class `::placeholder` see [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-placeholder)